# Square Feet versus Square Foot

Tags: word-choice, syntactic-analysis, descriptive-grammar, style-manuals

The sentence is

> The project would construct a 2000 square (foot/feet) kitchen.'

I put 'The project would construct a 2000 square feet kitchen.'

My senior reviewer changed *feet* to *foot*. Why?

If I switch up the order, feet definitely sounds better:

> The project would construct a kitchen with a floor area of 2000 square feet.

Online searches say that foot is used to refer to a singular unit of measurement (e.g. the area is one square foot). They also say that people generally use 'square foot' to describe the size of a room or space.

If I were to say it out loud, I would be inclined to say 'the apartment has a 2000 square foot kitchen, and the living room is 2000 square feet.'

Comment: *If I were to say it out loud, I would be inclined to say 'the apartment has a 2000 square foot kitchen, and the living room is 2000 square feet.'* This is correct and the top answer on the linked question explains why.

Comment: _They also say that people generally use 'square foot' to describe the size of a room or space._  That's why your reviewer changed it.,